# How to convert this query string into LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, oop

I am doing a final project in a C# class where I have to build a Hotel Management system, but I am currently stuck on checking if a room is already booked between two dates. I have tried to figure it out on my own, but I do not know how to convert this query string into LINQ.

Any help?

```
query = "SELECT * FROM Suites WHERE SuiteType = " + suitetype + " AND NumberOfAdultsAllowed >= " + adults + " AND NumberOfChildrenAllowed >= " + children + " AND ";
query += "Suites.SuiteNumber NOT IN (SELECT SuiteNumber FROM Bookings WHERE ";
query += "(StartDate BETWEEN @_start AND @_end) OR ";
query += "(EndDate BETWEEN @_start AND @_end) OR ";
query += "(@_start BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate) OR ";
query += "(@_end BETWEEN StartDate and EndDate) OR ";
query += "(@_start <= StartDate and @_end >= EndDate) OR ";
query += "(@_start >= @_end))";
```

I thought of first getting all rooms by

```
var querySearch = from q in db.Suites
                  where q.SuiteType == suitetype
                  select q;
```

and then checking it against another query that checks if suite number is in table `Bookings` and if it is between the dates specified.

But I get lost everytime.

Comment: What is your reason for converting a perfectly good SQL statement to Linq? Are you required to use Linq for your Final project?

Comment: @MichaelZ. Yes, we have to use LINQ to SQL as one of the requirements... otherwise I would go for simple SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty basic.  The only wrinkle is the sub-select, which you can do as follows.

Some of your bookings logic is a bit redundant, it's impossible for a date that is in between both start and end to not also have either the start or end be between the start/end date.  So you can reduce this a bit.

Also, the last or condition invalidates almost all of the previous logic, as it includes any date that has the end come after the start.

Note: This is untested, but should work.

```
var bookings = from b in db.Bookings
               where (b.StartDate >= start && b.StartDate <= end)
               || (b.EndDate >= start && b.EndDate <= end) select b.SuiteNumber;

var querySearch = from q in db.Suites
              where q.SuiteType == suitetype
              && q.NumberOfAdultsAllowed >= adults
              && q.NumberOfChildrenAllowed >= children
              && !bookings.Contains(q.SuiteNumber)
              select q;
```

Comment: Shouldn't he use `.Except(...)`

Comment: If you have to break a SQL statement into multiple Linq queries then it's probably not worth it. You're actually doing more processing than you would if you just used the SQL. Maybe run the SQL and then use Linq against the returned DataTable.

Comment: @MichaelZ. maybe, but as far as I know unless you call ToList or something similar, a query won't be executed. Multiple lines of code can still result a single query unless I'm wrong about this ? Even both lines of code listed won't actually execute any SQL until the results are fetched/iterated?

Comment: @RobertNoack it may be true that the two queries are run as one. Let me see if I can test this in LinqPad. LinqPad allows you to see a SQL view of your Linq to SQL, but it may not show a single SQL for two Linq queries. If I'm successful, I will post my results here.

Comment: @RobertNoack you are correct, I just tested. Two linq queries joined together in a third linq query will produce a single SQL statement.

Comment: @MichaelZ. - I disagree with your assessment, you can break linq queries up in to many pieces for readability.  I could have just as easily use a let statement to make it all one query, but choose to break it apart to be easier to read.

Comment: @MatthewWhited - Good catch, I missed the NOT IN

Comment: I often follow the pattern of building up an IQueryable across multiple statements, especially when the where clause depends on various parameters that are passed in. No actual SQL is used against the database until you attempt to read data from the IQueryable.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch yes you are right. I learned something doing a test with it. I'm a database developer that has just started to get into Linq to SQL. At this point I feel like querying is much harder with Linq than just using SQL,  but that's probably only because I have many years of SQL experience. Thank you for correcting me. That's how I learn.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch You answer works, only change I had to make is use  `.Contains` instead of `.Execpt`!

Comment: @MichaelZ. While I am still learning (still in school), I still find regular SQL queries easier, but the power of LINQ is just mindblowing.

Comment: You will actually need to inverse the logic when using except.  It excludes items from the left side if they are in the right. You can also say `!bookings.Contains(...)`.  I'd have to see the generated SQL and have the datamodel to optimize the query more.

Comment: @MatthewWhited - yeah, I think the !contains is easier to understand.

Comment: @Denis, I think you want, as Matthew mentions, !bookings.Contains() rather than just bookings.Contains, at least based on the logic in the SQL statement that use NOT IN.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Yes, I am using ``!bookings.Contains`` as I was reading the reply and saw the error you made before correcting it. It works perfectly!